# Add layer between two layers in saved model tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a h5 file of a model for which I don't have the code used to build it. I want to load the model, select two layers and insert between these layers a custom one. I tried the following code

```py
model = keras.models.load_model('weights.h5')
previous_layer = model.layers[index_of_previous_layer]
next_layer = model.layers[index_of_next_layer]
custom_layer = Custom(...)
previous_output = previous_layer.output
custom_output = custom_layer(previous_output)
next_layer.input = custom_output
```

But I get this error

```
AttributeError: Can't set the attribute "input", 
likely because it conflicts with an existing read-only @property of the object. 
Please choose a different name.
```

Is there a way to add a layer between two layers of a saved model? Does it work even if the model has skip connections?

EDIT
I tried what Sajan suggests in the comment

```
previous_layer = model.layers[index_of_previous_layer]
next_layer = model.layers[index_of_next_layer]
custom_layer = Custom(...)

prev = keras.Model(model.input, previous_layer.output)
after = keras.Model(next_layer.input, model.output)

final = keras.Sequential()
final.add(prev)
final.add(custom_layer)
final.add(after)
```

and while it does work for linear models it fails if applied to models with skip connections.

The following code throws an error

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Add

class Multiplier(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, rate, **kwargs):
        super(Multiplier, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.__rate = rate

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.multiply(inputs, self.__rate)

def small_model_with_skip_connections(input_shape):
    # Input layer
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    
    # Convolutional block 1
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    skip1 = Add()([conv1, conv2])  # Skip connection
    
    # Convolutional block 2
    conv3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(skip1)
    conv4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    skip2 = Add()([skip1, conv4])  # Skip connection
    
    # Convolutional block 3
    conv5 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(skip2)
    conv6 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)
    skip3 = Add()([skip2, conv6])  # Skip connection
    
    # Output layer
    output = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(skip3)
    
    # Create the model
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
    
    return model

skipmodel = small_model_with_skip_connections((32,32,3))
previous_layer = skipmodel.layers[4]
next_layer = skipmodel.layers[5]
custom_layer = Multiplier(600)

prev = keras.Model(skipmodel.input, previous_layer.output)
after = keras.Model(next_layer.input, skipmodel.output)

final = keras.Sequential()
final.add(prev)
final.add(custom_layer)
final.add(after)
```

The error it throws is the following

```
ValueError: Found input tensor cannot be reached given provided output tensors. Please make sure the tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_2'), name='input_2', description="created by layer 'input_2'") is included in the model inputs when building functional model.
```

I am still unable to add a layer in the middle of a model with skip connections

Comment: You can separate the model and create new model, something like: `prev = Model(input, previous_layer.output)`, `custom = prev(custom_layer)`, after popping layers before next_layer `end = Model(next_layer.input, full_model.output)(custom)` and finally compiling all as `Model(prev.input, end.output)`. If you can share some reproducible code, i can try it

Comment: I edited my original question to address your suggestion @SajanGohil

Comment: Sorry, i missed the skip connection part. It will be a bit difficult with the skip connection part. If you have the full model and not just weights, can you rebuild the model from the configuration?

Comment: Unfortunately I only have the weights which makes the task complex, otherwise it would be pretty straightforward.